# Is there a reason why my variable doesn't show? - HTML

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I'm making a project with Java and Html, so I'm using Thymeleaf to get the information on the HTML. Everything works fine but one variable.

Java

```
static int TotalIncome;
    static int Balance;
    public static void Incomes(int IncomeAmount, Model model){
        TotalIncome = IncomeAmount;
        Balance = IncomeAmount - lastMoneyValue;

        model.addAttribute("TotalIncome", TotalIncome);
        model.addAttribute("Balance", Balance);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="div-income">
    <h2 class="h2-income">INCOME</h2>
    <span class="span-tIncome" th:text ="${TotalIncome}">
    </span>

    <h2 class="h2-tBalance">CURRENT BALANCE</h2>
</div>
```

The problem is it doesn't show Income, can someone tell me why?

When I run it:

[image]

On my terminal:

[image]

Comment: Did you try: <span class="span-tIncome" th:value ="${TotalIncome}">

Comment: Or try th:utext instead of th:text. Let me know if it works

Comment: I have tried this in my machine, it is working fine. Can you please do one thing ? just remove the static keyword and restart the application and check once.
Let me know